# regarding a script launching a daemon process

Tags: java, daemon, daemons

I am quite new to the daemon process and java, and was just given the following script for running a daemon process. I can generally understand the structure of this script. But I have several questions:

What do “Install”, “StdOutput”, “StartClass” and “StartMode” mean here? Looks to me “Install” is an operations and “StdOutput” is a file name; and “StartClass” is just a java class file. And this script is just a list of these information. Is my understanding correct?

```
commons-daemon-1.0.8-bin-windows\prunsrv.exe//AB/TestService   
--Classpath="D:\TESTFOLDER\TestService.jar;D:\TESTFOLDER\;D:\TESTFOLDER\lib\weka.jar; 
" --LogPath="d:\TESTFOLDER\logs\testprocess.log" --Install="d:\TESTFOLDER\commons-
 daemon-1.0.8-bin-windows\prunsrv.exe" --StdOutput="d:\TESTFOLDER\logs\std.out" 
--StartClass="com.Group.TestService" --StartMode=Java --JavaHome="c:\Program Files\Java
\jdk1.6.0_02" --Jvm="c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_02\jre\bin\jvm.dll"
```

Answer (score 0):

The following page should help you:
http://commons.apache.org/daemon/procrun.html

It explains what procrun is and what each of the command line parameters are. i.e. `--StdOutput`:
*Redirected stdout filename. If named auto file is created inside LogPath with the name service-stdout.YEAR-MONTH-DAY.log.*